# Can I invoke another software using C++ and can I interface my c++ code to a gui?

Tags: visual-c++

My application would run on Windows. Would I be able to invoke and run another application (say,provide the files selected by the user in the GUI to Matlab) using system() command while my C++ program is still running?

Can't SPAWN() and exec() do the job?

Does VisualC++ provide some mechanism or libraries to interface GUI with my C++ code?
Can you suggest me some compiler to do the job?
Can you suggest me some tutorials on QT or FLTK?

Answer (score 0):

Sure under windows you can start a programm using CreateProcess (which is more low level) or ShellExecute (which is simpler).

If you want to create a GUI with Visual C++ the simplest thing is to use MFC. Is is not very beautyful (neither the gui, nor the code) but it is simple to develop since you have designer support.